# Scroll without scroll bar in IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I have created a div with `overflow:auto`.In Chrome the scroll bar is not visible and also scrolling.

How can I make the similar in IE and FireFox? Because IE and Firefox showing the scroll bar.How can I achieve scroll without the scroll bar.

Comment: Have you tried setting overflow property to visible?

Answer (score 1):

In IE use the following code in parent div

```
.parent{
-ms-overflow-style :none;   
}

.child{
overflow:auto;
}
```